# How to make fetch request at a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, fetch

I have a react app that utilizes fetch to get and post/patch data from/to a rails backend. The way I currently have it, I've just copied and pasted the fetch request into each child component but that seems really irrational. I wanted to know if there's a way to do dynamically coded fetch get/post/patch requests in the parent component (my component list) instead of having to rewrite the fetch requests in every component that needs it. Below is the code I'm using:

First child component fetch request from file components/scripts/script8/page3.js:

```js
    state = {
        handleclick: {
        check_words: null,
        x_words: ''
        },
        text: {}
    }
        handleClick = (e, letter) => {
            if (letter === 'c'){
                this.setState({handleclick: {check_words: <Checked />, x_words: ''}})
            }
            else if (letter === 'x'){
                this.setState({handleclick: {check_words : null, x_words: "Go to the next page"}})
            }
        }

        handleScroll=()=>{
            window.scroll({top:0, behavior:'smooth'})
        }
        
        componentDidMount() {
            this.handleScroll()
            axios.get("http://localhost:3001/texts")
            .then(res => {
                const texts = res.data;
                for (const txt of texts){
                    if (txt.sheet === "8"){
                        this.setState({
                            text: {...this.state.text, [txt.id_tag]: txt}
                        })
                    }
                }
                  
        })
    }

        handleChange = (event) => {
            this.setState({text: {...this.state.text, [event.target.id]: {value: event.target.value, id_tag: event.target.id}}})
            if (event.target.id in this.state.text){
                axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/texts/${this.state.text[event.target.id].id}`, {value: event.target.value, id_tag: event.target.id, sheet: "8"})
        }
            else {
                axios.post("http://localhost:3001/texts", {value: event.target.value, id_tag: event.target.id, sheet: "8" })
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Second child component fetch request from components/scripts/script3/page4.js:

```js
    state = {
        text: {}
    }
    handleScroll=()=>{
        window.scroll({top:0,behavior:'smooth'})
    
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleScroll()
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/texts")
        .then(res => {
            const texts = res.data;
            for (const txt of texts){
                if (txt.sheet === "3"){
                    this.setState({
                        text: {...this.state.text, [txt.id_tag]: txt}
                    })
                }
            }
              
    })
}

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({text: {...this.state.text, [event.target.id]: {value: event.target.value, id_tag: event.target.id}}})
        if (event.target.id in this.state.text){
            axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/texts/${this.state.text[event.target.id].id}`, {value: event.target.value, id_tag: event.target.id, sheet: "3"})
    }
        else {
            axios.post("http://localhost:3001/texts", {value: event.target.value, id_tag: event.target.id, sheet: "3" })
        }
    }
    

    getValue = (id) => {
        for (const i in this.state.text){
            if (this.state.text[i].id_tag === id){
                return this.state.text[i].value;
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
```

Notice the only difference is which sheet it is. On top of that, within script8 for example, two files may have identical fetch functions.

Parent component currently where I call the child component:

```js
class Script8List extends Component {

    state = {button_use: {button_back: false, button_forward: true}, 
    component_list: [<Page1 />, <Page2 />, <Page3 />, <Page4 />, <Page5 />, <Page6 />, <Page7 />, <Page8 />, <Page9 />, <Page10 />, <Page11 />, <Page12 />], 
    pagePos: 0}
    
    handleClick = (letter) => {//This determines which button was pressed
      if (letter === 'b'){
        this.setState((prevState) => ({pagePos: prevState.pagePos - 1}))
      }
      else {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({pagePos: prevState.pagePos + 1}))
      }
      
    }
    
    render() {
      return(
      <div className="Script8">{this.state.component_list[this.state.pagePos]}
        <div id="buttonDiv">
          {this.state.pagePos === 0 ? null :  <img alt="left arrow back" src={larrow} onClick={() => this.handleClick('b')} className="left arrow button"/>}
          {this.state.pagePos === this.state.component_list.length - 1 ? null :  <img alt="right arrow forward" src={rarrow} onClick={() => this.handleClick('f')} className="right arrow button"/>}
        </div>
        <h3 className="page_num">{this.state.pagePos + 1}</h3>
      </div>
      )
    }
  }

export default Script8List;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is what I would want the parent component to look like:

```js
class Script8List extends Component {

    state = {button_use: {button_back: false, button_forward: true}, 
    component_list: [<Page1 />, <Page2 />, <Page3 />, <Page4 />, <Page5 />, <Page6 />, <Page7 />, <Page8 />, <Page9 />, <Page10 />, <Page11 />, <Page12 />], 
    pagePos: 0}
    
    handleClick = (letter) => {//This determines which button was pressed
      if (letter === 'b'){
        this.setState((prevState) => ({pagePos: prevState.pagePos - 1}))
      }
      else {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({pagePos: prevState.pagePos + 1}))
      }
      
    }
    


handleClick = (e, letter) => {
    if (letter === 'c'){
        this.setState({handleclick: {check_words: <Checked />, x_words: ''}})
    }
    else if (letter === 'x'){
        this.setState({handleclick: {check_words : null, x_words: "Go to the next page"}})
    }
}

handleScroll=()=>{
    window.scroll({top:0, behavior:'smooth'})
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.handleScroll()
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/texts")
    .then(res => {
        const texts = res.data;
        for (const txt of texts){
            if (txt.sheet === {current_sheet}){
                this.setState({
                    text: {...this.state.text, [txt.id_tag]: txt}
                })
            }
        }
          
})
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({text: {...this.state.text, [event.target.id]: {value: event.target.value, id_tag: event.target.id}}})
    if (event.target.id in this.state.text){
        axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/texts/${this.state.text[event.target.id].id}`, {value: event.target.value, id_tag: event.target.id, sheet: {current_sheet}})
}
    else {
        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/texts", {value: event.target.value, id_tag: event.target.id, sheet: {current_sheet} })
    }
}
    render() {
      return(
      <div className="Script8">{this.state.component_list[this.state.pagePos]}
        <div id="buttonDiv">
          {this.state.pagePos === 0 ? null :  <img alt="left arrow back" src={larrow} onClick={() => this.handleClick('b')} className="left arrow button"/>}
          {this.state.pagePos === this.state.component_list.length - 1 ? null :  <img alt="right arrow forward" src={rarrow} onClick={() => this.handleClick('f')} className="right arrow button"/>}
        </div>
        <h3 className="page_num">{this.state.pagePos + 1}</h3>
      </div>
      )
    }
  }

export default Script8List;
```

My only problem is that I don't know how to do it dynamically in such a way that I can send information up to the parent component in real time while also keeping the page as is. Part of the problem is that I make these calls anytime something changes in a textbox so I need to know how to converse between the two.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Since you are talking about parent/children components can you show a parent and a child and describe exactly where the problem is? Are you just trying to make a reusable function for each component (like a useApi hook?)

Comment: @windowsill That's my bad I will edit the main post so that you can better understand.

Comment: Do all the child component use the same api call to /texts? You still have not shown any duplication even though you say your problem is with duplication.

Comment: Please update your question to include the duplication.

Comment: @windowsill ah damn okay I updated it to include this.

Comment: Are you having to call `axios.get("http://localhost:3001/texts")` in every child component? Call it once in the parent and pass down the data that each child needs as props. You're going to have other problems though because 1. components are not appropriate state values, and 2. setState is an async function so calling it many times in a for loop does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have any idea what you're main problem is, but it might help if you see a minimal example of a parent that shares api data with its children.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [apiResults, setApiResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => onRefresh(), []);

  const onRefresh = () => axios.get().then(setApiResults);

  return <>
    <Child data={apiResults.find(r => r.page === 2)} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
    <Child data={apiResults.find(r => r.page === 3)} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
  <>;
};

const Child = ({data, onRefresh}) => {
  // ...
};
```